# How to Solve runtime error 6 in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code

```
TextBox50.Value = Round((CDbl(TextBox3.Value) / (CDbl(Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4").Value)) - 1) * 100, 1) & "%"
```

The value of `TextBox3 = Value` present in `Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4")`.

The issue is if the value of Range(O4) is zero, then it essentially means 0/0 which is why I am getting runtime 6, overflow error.

Is there anyway I can replace 0/0 with 0.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IIF():

```
TextBox50.Value = Round((CDbl(TextBox3.Value) / IIF(CDbl(Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4")=0,1,CDbl(Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4")))
```

Which will return the value in TextBox3 if the other is 0.

Comment: Is there anyway where I can show the output as "NA" or "-" or "NULL"

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for situation where you have a divide by zero issue:

```
If CDbl(Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4").Value) = 0 Then
   TextBox50.Value = (0 - 1) * 100, 1) & "%"
Else
    TextBox50.Value = Round((CDbl(TextBox3.Value) / (CDbl(Worksheets("calculation").Range("O4").Value)) - 1) * 100, 1) & "%"
End If
```