# How to solve runtime error 11 division by 0 in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have the following code.....

```
private sub textbox1_change()
if textbox1.value = "" then exit sub 
if textbox2.value = "" then exit sub 
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value)
end sub 
private sub textbox2_change()
if textbox1.value = "" then exit sub
if textbox2.value = "" then exit sub
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value)
end sub
```

Whenever textbox2 has a zero value there will be a message box prompting runtime error 11; division by zero. I tried to resolve it by using IIF condition as suggested by the user **Scott Craner** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231638/how-to-solve-runtime-error-6-in-vba)

```
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value)/IIF(cdbl(textbox2.value) = 0 , 1 , cdbl(textbox2.value) )
```

I want to know if I can somehow assign the value of textbox3 as "NULL" or "NA" or "-" if the denominator is zero. I could not find anything credible on the internet.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to check the denominator value before you do the calculation.  then a simple If...else will suffice.

```
If textbox2.value = 0 Or IsEmpty(textbox2.Value) Then
      textbox3.Value = "Null" 'Or "NA" or whatever you'd like
Else
      textbox3.Value = cDbl(textbox1.Value) / CDbl(textbox2.Value)
End If
```

Comment: I get the compile error " Block If without end if " if I do it this way

Comment: Then you have another issue in your code. Do you have any `For` loops without a next? Or another `If` statement without a corresponding `End If`?

Comment: @Vinaybilla as Kyle said, that is not an issue with this code.  You must be having an issue elsewhere

Comment: @Vinaybilla I just adjusted my code.  I realize the issue is that textbox2.value is being passed not as "0" but as the empty string "", this code should work now

Answer (score 1):

Where you have the line: -

```
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value)
```

Change if for the below:-

```
textbox3.value = iif(cdbl(textbox2.value)=0,"N\A", cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value))
```

This is stating that if `textbox2` is zero then output 'N\A', else do the division as normal (i.e. `textbox1` / `textbox2`).

Comment: doesn't really answer OP's question since they are asking to have the value be "Null" etc, not textbox1.value.  Of course, if you change that first condition to be "Null" then this does work perfectly fine

Comment: I tried this but the runtime error still appears and vba asks me to debug

Comment: Also, if textbox1.value =0 then we get runtime 6 error

Answer (score 1):

Replace all of your code: -

```
private sub textbox1_change()
if textbox1.value = "" then exit sub 
if textbox2.value = "" then exit sub 
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value)
end sub 
private sub textbox2_change()
if textbox1.value = "" then exit sub
if textbox2.value = "" then exit sub
textbox3.value = cdbl(textbox1.value) / cdbl(textbox2.value)
end sub
```

With this code: -

```
Private Sub textbox1_change()
ShowResult
End Sub
Private Sub textbox2_change()
ShowResult
End Sub
Private Sub ShowResult()
Dim Str1        As String
Dim Str2        As String
Str1 = Trim(textbox1.Value)
Str2 = Trim(textbox2.Value)
If (Str1 = "") Or (Str2 = "") Then Exit Sub
If (IsDouble(Str1) = False) Or (IsDouble(Str2) = False) Then
    textbox3.Value = "N\A"
Else
    If (CDbl(Str2) = 0) Or ((CDbl(Str2) + CDbl(Str1)) = 0) Then
        textbox3.Value = "N\A"
    Else
        textbox3.Value = CDbl(Str1) / CDbl(Str2)
    End If
End If
End Sub
Private Function IsDouble(ByVal StrValue As String) As Boolean
Dim DblTest As Double
On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
DblTest = CDbl(StrValue)
IsDouble = True
Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
Err.Clear
End Function
```

This will check for values that can't be `Double` data types (i.e. a string) and bad division (i.e. error code 6 and 11).

EDIT: -
The below is walkthrough of what is happening in the above code.

The procedures `textbox1_change` and `textbox2_change` are doing the same thing so to avoid repetition of code; they both call on the one instance of that code.

```
Private Sub textbox1_change()
ShowResult
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_change()
ShowResult
End Sub
```

After that, there is the new procedure `ShowResult` that holds the single instance of the code that `textbox1_change` and `textbox2_change` call upon.

```
Private Sub ShowResult()
Dim Str1        As String
Dim Str2        As String
Str1 = Trim(textbox1.Value)
Str2 = Trim(textbox2.Value)
If (Str1 = "") Or (Str2 = "") Then Exit Sub
If (IsDouble(Str1) = False) Or (IsDouble(Str2) = False) Then
    textbox3.Value = "N\A"
Else
    If (CDbl(Str2) = 0) Or ((CDbl(Str2) + CDbl(Str1)) = 0) Then
        textbox3.Value = "N\A"
    Else
        textbox3.Value = CDbl(Str1) / CDbl(Str2)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The `ShowResult` code does a number of checks.

First it places `textbox1` into `Str1` and `textbox2` into `Str2` and using `trim` on them. Trim means that leading and trailing spaces are removed. For example if the `textbox1` value was " " (maybe done by copy and paste by the user) then technically it's not empty and could cause an error.

```
Dim Str1        As String
Dim Str2        As String
Str1 = Trim(textbox1.Value)
Str2 = Trim(textbox2.Value)
```

The next check is if either value is empty then exit the procedure, much like you did before but now on a single line.

```
If (Str1 = "") Or (Str2 = "") Then Exit Sub
```

The next check calls another procedure that does a check to ensure the value could be converted to a double. for Example `CDbl("Hello World!")` would fail because it's not a number to begin with. So this check gets around that potential issue, if its not a number that can be divided then output 'N\A'.

```
If (IsDouble(Str1) = False) Or (IsDouble(Str2) = False) Then
    textbox3.Value = "N\A"
```

The final check is that if the second value is zero or both are zero then "N\A2 is output, else the division is done and output.

```
If (CDbl(Str2) = 0) Or ((CDbl(Str2) + CDbl(Str1)) = 0) Then
    textbox3.Value = "N\A"
Else
    textbox3.Value = CDbl(Str1) / CDbl(Str2)
End If
```

This is the final procedure that was called by `ShowResult` to check the value could be converted to a `Double` data type. It tried to do the conversion, if an error occurs the error is cleared and `false` (by default) will be returned to the caller, if there is no error then `true` is output.

```
Private Function IsDouble(ByVal StrValue As String) As Boolean
Dim DblTest As Double
On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
DblTest = CDbl(StrValue)
IsDouble = True
Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
Err.Clear
End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot gary.. that just does the trick but I did not understand how it works. Please walk me through the solution

Comment: I'm glad it helped and really glad you wanted further explanation and didnt just use it and walk away! I've edited the answer, hope it helps.